# Show transit stations, restaurants and other places on iOS 6 MKMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6, mkmapview

Is it possible to show businesses, restaurants, transit stations, parks, etc. on an MKMapView in your own app?

Below is a picture of how this looks in the iOS 6 Maps app. Can I do the same in my own app? How?

[image: MKMapView with businesses]

Comment: Although it would be very *very* nice to have this feature in `MKMapViews`, I think it's a feature Apple reserved for their own Maps app. However, the release of [iOS 6.1 brings a search feature](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6_1.html) you can add to your app which will return all the matching places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although it would be very very nice to have this feature in MKMapViews, I think it's a feature Apple reserved for their own Maps app. However, the release of [iOS 6.1 brings a search](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniOS/Articles/iOS6_1.html) feature you can add to your app which will return all the matching places.

iOS 7 also opens many new maps APIs - I'll add more details when the OS goes public.

You could also check out the [Foursquare API](https://developer.foursquare.com). You'd probably interested in their [Venue's Platform](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/venues):

> Just need a database of places? The Venues Platform allows developers to search for places and access a wealth of information about them, including addresses, popularity, tips, and photos. It's available free and without any user authentication, as long as applications include adequate attribution.